# Different TOC layout TeX Live 2021 vs. 2022

Tags: table-of-contents, texlive, classicthesis, arsclassica

when compiling the following MWE with TeX Live 2021 as distribution the result (first fig.) differs from the compilation using Tex Live 2022 (second fig., good to test with Overleaf). The spaced low small caps are not present anymore in the toc (2022 version), but this isn't the "right" version of the authors of ClassicThesis/ArsClassica. Maybe it's due to the tocloft package? Anyone has an idea to solve this problem?

Best regards!

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers]{classicthesis} %,manychapters

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
    
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}
    
\tableofcontents
    
\chapter{Lipsum}
\lipsum
    
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Live 2021]

[image: Tex Live 2022]

Comment: I get the same output under up to date TL2021 and TL2022. I do get the first result using up to date TL2020. So the change is more likely to have happened between TL2020 and the last updates for TL2021 (not that Overleaf does not really update their installations during the TL live span).

Comment: Given the warnings in the log, you probably should not combine `classicthesis` and `scrbook` in the first place.

Comment: From the answer `tocloft` has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`microtype` (loaded by `classicthesis`) adds now various patches to optimize the protrusion, and one of them clashes with the small caps code from `classicthesis`.

You can disable the patches. I removed the inputenc package as utf8 is the default since a few years anyway.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{nopatch}{microtype}

\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers]{classicthesis} %,manychapters

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lipsum}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This patch does not work for me any more. It only sets the first letter of chapter titles into small caps. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709980/classicthesis-does-not-give-me-smallcaps-in-headings

Comment: @Floris my example still works in texlive 2024, I just tried that. Also it doesn't patch anything, it only disables an interfering microtype patch.