# Classicthesis: chapter titles are not small capitals in TOC

Tags: classicthesis, small-caps

My understanding of the `classicthesis` template is that the chapter titles in the TOC are typeset as small capitals like the Introduction chapter here (taken from the classicthesis manual):

[image]

However, when I try this, my chapter titles are not small capitals. Here is an MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[%
    twoside, openright, titlepage, numbers=noenddot,%
    cleardoublepage=empty,%
    abstractoff,%
    BCOR=5.5mm, paper=a5, fontsize=10pt,
]{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{%
  dottedtoc,%
  eulerchapternumbers,
  floatperchapter, pdfspacing,%
  beramono,%
  a5paper,%
}{classicthesis}
\usepackage{classicthesis}


\begin{document}

% TOC
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % <-- 2 includes up to subsections in the ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % <-- 3 numbers up to subsubsections
\manualmark%
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 2}

\end{document}
```

which renders as

[image]

I would like to have the chapter titles as small capitals in the TOC. How can I achieve that?

**Edit 1**
I downloaded the example `classicthesis-book.tex` from the official package ([link](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/Examples)). The same problem happens.

**Edit 2**
I'm compiling this on Overleaf, but I also tried this locally with the same result.

Comment: Have you seen all the incompatibility warnings in the `log` file? Maybe you should not combine `scrreprt` with `classicthesis`. However, the problem does also occur with `report`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I looked at the `ClassicThesis.tex` that can be downloaded as part of the official package, where they also use `scrreprt`, so I somehow assumed this would be compatible. I also copied one of their examples (`classicthesis-book.tex`) and the same problem happens.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, thanks a lot!! I would have never found that post with the keywords I was using.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I would recommend adding that as an answer so it can get marked as such. Currently, mine is marked, and I feel as if I am hogging reputation that rightfully belongs to you.

Comment: Happy to change the accepted mark to a future answer from @UlrikeFischer.

Comment: @BrightBulb123 I voted to close this here as duplicate, that is the recommended way to handle that. And don't worry about my reputation, I'm rich enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) has [pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699020/classicthesis-chapter-titles-are-not-small-capitals-in-toc#comment1736990_699020), this is answered in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654208/different-toc-layout-tex-live-2021-vs-2022), so you should use this.

However, I've also found a workaround by putting [`\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\scshape}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123576/294117) in the preamble (after `classicthesis` has been loaded). Beware, this is a bit "hacky" and I would strongly recommend doing what Ulrike Fischer sugggests.

Comment: That solved it, thanks a bunch!