# `classicthesis` does not give me smallcaps in headings

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, classicthesis, persian, multilingual

I am using `classicthesis` in a document that also needs to use Persian text (in Arabic script). I am using `polyglossia` and `XeLaTeX` with this. I want the main font to be Palatino/TeX Gyre Pagella. Unfortunately, I am stuck with headings that are Palatino, but not in small caps. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. For some headings, the first letter is compiled in small caps, but the remainder isn't.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[
                    a4paper,
                    fontsize=11pt
                    ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xunicode}   
\usepackage{hyperref}

\PassOptionsToPackage{nopatch}{microtype}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{xurl}


\usepackage[
                eulerchapternumbers=true,
                tocaligned=true,
                dottedtoc=true,
                drafting=true,
                linedheaders=true,
                style=classicthesis,
                ]{classicthesis}        

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  

\usepackage[babelshorthands=false]{polyglossia} 

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguages{persian, english, french, polish}

\newfontfamily\persianfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.1]{Sahel}
\newfontfamily\persiandigitsfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage[largesc,osf]{newpxtext}
\linespread{1.05} 


\begin{document}
    \frenchspacing
    \raggedbottom
    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage
    \chapter{Testkapitel}
    \section{Testabschnitt}
\end{document}
```

I came along and adopted [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654208/different-toc-layout-tex-live-2021-vs-2022), but I did not get me anywhere, unfortunately.

Addition (Feb 20): I just realized that there is also some relevant error messages. I don't know what they're telling me though:

In verse.sty:

```
34: Command \theHpoemline already defined. ...}{\arabic{verse@envctr}.\arabic{poemline}}
```

In the MWE above:

```
104: Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
104: Missing font identifier. \begin{document}
104: Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{document}
```

Comment: you should clean up and shorten your preamble. As an example it is too long (and your various font setting overwrite each other). Do not generally available fonts like Sahel, use Amiri. Regarding the error: Load the verse package before hyperref (this is no longer needed with the newest version but you don't seem to have that).

Answer (score 1):

If I remove all the interfering and contradicting font packages and  disable as mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654221/2388 the microtype patches small caps works fine. The error from the verse package can be avoid either by updating to the newest version of by loading it before hyperref.

```
\documentclass[
twoside,
openright,
titlepage,
numbers=noenddot,
headinclude,
footinclude,
a4paper,
fontsize=11pt
]{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{nopatch}{microtype}
\usepackage[
palatino=true,
eulerchapternumbers=true,
tocaligned=true,
dottedtoc=true,
drafting=true,
linedheaders=true,
style=classicthesis,
]{classicthesis}        

\usepackage[babelshorthands=false]{polyglossia} 

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguages{persian, english, french, polish}

% Persische Schrift

\newfontfamily\persianfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.1]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\persiandigitsfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Testkapitel}
    \section{Testabschnitt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the heading "Inhaltsverzeichnis" itself, as well as all other headings in the document should also be in small caps, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Also, oddly this still compiles like before for me: ![image](https://picsur.org/i/707f8215-5946-4658-acd6-f9c9a201515e.jpg)

Comment: LuaLaTeX renders your code correctly, very different to what XeTeX outputs!

Comment: Yes classicthesis handles every engine differently which makes debugging rather painful. Personally i wouldn't use it.